# What should be committed or ignored in git for Codeception tests?

Tags: git, testing, phpunit, codeception

I look through the Codeception files and I see .gitkeep in the tests/_data/ directory. That is the directory that should hold a database dump. That dump is the database from which the site will be restored. That same directory also, upon initialization, contains a .gitkeep file which indicates to me that the directory "should be committed, but there isn't anything in it right now". 
Now, I'm not going to commit my database to my repo, but should that one file be ignored or should the whole directory be ignored? Are there other files are directories that should be ignored? Is there a best-practice to follow when working with .git and automated tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides ignoring `tests/_support/_generated`, you should also ignore `tests/_output` , since that output is generated when running the tests. 
And, if you are using for example Laravel style .env configuration files, you probably want to ignore the `.env` file as well.

Using .env files you can also commit codeception's .yml config files, because anything that would be different across environments would be defined in the .env.

Of course, you need to commit your database dump too, if you use one. Like Naktibalda said, it should only contain necessary data. 
But there are many other ways to setup you test database with the necessary data, besides using a full dump.

Besides that, I also commit `codecept.phar`, `chromedriver` and `selenium` to our project. It makes it easier for the team that they can pull the project and run the tests immediately with the correct versions of those binaries.

Comment: When I asked this question I was specifically thinking about the output and specific tests. For instance, one of my tests is to log into the site. To that end, I had to supply login information. I obviously don't want to commit that. I also don't want to commit a database dump because it contains the same information. Besides, isn't the database dump used for only a moment in order to restore the original database? There are also database connection files that contain db names and passwords. Even the output files display the passwords used in specific tests.

Comment: Any passwords can be in the .env file, which will be ignored. The database dump should contain test users, and even if some users are the same on test and on live, they should not  have the same passwords as you have on the live database.

Answer (score 0):

Content `tests/_support/_generated` should be ignored if it currently isn't.

You should only put files that are necessary for your tests to `tests/_data`, so nothing in that directory should be ignored.
It isn't necessary to commit content of your live database to git, what you have to do instead is prepare a small sql file containing only data necessary for your tests and commit that file.